# Reflective injector that allows to inject dependencies outside of constructor parameters in nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I need to get access to a service inside my model class. That service has a bunch of injection of its own, so it would be great if I could get an instance of that service inside that class model.
Angular, for example, has a reflective injector that allows to do that, I remember seeing somewhere an example of instantiating a service with the help of the nestjs reflector but I couldn't find that example, it was pretty long ago.
I don't know if I had to add any code to the question. I just have a model class and I need to use a service there. I need to inject it not through the class constructor, that's it, I believe.

How do I do that?

EDIT:

Seems like nest has a reflector but I also have to inject it...my goodness...it doesn't have a reflective injector akin to that in Angular.

In Angluar you don't have to inject the reflector itself...apparently it's not always suitable to do that...